# pandas None of [] are in the index

Tags: python, pandas

i am  trying to divide my df to few variables and getting error `None of [[col1, col2, col3]] are in the [index]`

i am doing like that `a, b, c = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]`

also tried lead to np.array `a, b, c = np.array(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])`

and few more variants of `.values; .T[0], and a, b, c = df[['col1']], df[['col2']], df[['col3']]`

in all cases i got an error

df looks like

`col1 : list of floats  col2: float  col3 : float`

ty for ur help

Comment: @jezrael list of df columns(col1,col2,col3)

Comment: Or `print (df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])` working well?

Comment: df.columns.tolist() shows them

Comment: @jezrael `print (df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])` is fine

Comment: hmmm, do you need `a, b, c = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].to_numpy().T` ?

Comment: Make sure you don't overwrite your df somewhere just above. You said printing works well but then you get the error for the same thing when trying to unpack, so something must've changed in the meantime with the object itself (if it was a problem with unpacking itself, the error would be about unpacking, not some inner workings of pandas)

Comment: @h4z3 yeah, u r right, calling print if my function falls with this error, but i do not do anything with this df, he just passing to func as an argument, i tried to print this df at the first row of func and this falls